# android id erro

Tags: android, listview

I am trying to set up a list view and when i run in the emulator i am getting an error 'Your content must have a id attribute is android.R.id.list'.

Here is  my xml for the file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <!-- Main ListView
         Always give id value as list(@android:id/list)
    -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

When I check in the generated java files for R.id 'list' is not in there.  Any ideas how to fix this?

Tnanks

Comment: if you want to add an ID use `@+id/list` instead of `@android:id/list`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/mainListView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1" >
</ListView>
```

Try this out.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ListView
    android:id="@id/android:list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Try that

Answer (score 0):

when using `android:id="@android:id/list"` you are referring to id's already defined in the android system. To create your own id's you need to use the following:

```
<listview id="@+id/insertListNameHere">
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you're written is slightly incorrect.

Instead of,

```
<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Use,

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```